# split elements into groups haskell

Tags: list, haskell, indexing, split

Hey Im new to functional programming and learning haskell.
I'm wondering whether will i be able to split elements in a list and grouping them in two's.

I already saw the `splitAt` operations and it only splits at specified index value/ position

`splitAt 3 [1,2,3,4,5] -> [1,2,3][4,5]`

Now I'm wondering say I have a list where random characters `[A,S,D,F,G,H,J,K,U,Y,R,E,W,V,B,N]`, 
I want to split this as  `[A,S][D,F][G,H][J,K].... and so on`..

I' m totally stuck up in this !
Please help me out !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a function for that yourself:

```
mySplit :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
mySplit n [] = []
mySplit n xs = (take n xs):(mySplit n (drop n xs))
```

Demo:

```
λ> mySplit 2 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
λ> mySplit 2 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7]]
```

Another way would be to use the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.1.1/docs/Data-List-Split.html) package:

```
λ splitEvery 3 ['a'..'z']
["abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stu","vwx","yz"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also continue to use `splitAt`, you just have to recurse over it manually:

```
chunks :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunks n [] = []
chunks n xs = head : (chunks n tail)
    where (head, tail) = splitAt n xs

λ> chunks 2 [1,2,3,4,5])
[[1,2],[3,4],[5]]
```

I thought this might be more efficient (avoiding the need to evaluate `take` and `drop` explicitly), but according to the [documentation for Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html):

> It is equivalent to `(take n xs, drop n xs)` when n is not `_|_` (`splitAt _|_ xs = _|_`).

I guess there's always more than one way to do it! It is interesting to see how each answer uses a different method of pattern-matching.

Comment: `chunks n = takeWhile (not.null) . unfoldr (Just . splitAt n)`. or `unfoldr (list Nothing (Just . splitAt n))` with `list e ne xs = case xs of [] -> e; _ -> ne xs`. (["`list`"](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=t+-%3E+%28[t1]+-%3E+t%29+-%3E+[t1]+-%3E+t) by analogy with `maybe`). :)

Answer (score 2):

First when asking such a question, specify the type signature you want! So you want to create (given a constant sublist-length) from a flat list a whole list of lists. That suggests the signature

```
splitOfLen :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

Before you start implementing, it's clever to see if anybody has done that before:

- [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[[a]]) gives a whole lot of *similar* result, but none that really matches.
- [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Int+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[[a]]) shows that the function has been implemented in a whole lot of libraries, but really just as a local helper.

If you want to do it yourself, you should start with `splitAt` (which splits off *one* prefix) and progress to do that while anything remains:

```
splitsOfLen l xs = case splitAt l xs of
   (p, []) -> [p]
   (p, r) -> p : splitsOfLen l r
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a great function in **Data.Lists.Split** named `chunksOf` that with the parameter 2 wiLL pull pairs out of a list. `chunksOf` will pull the last odd element out of the list. Say given 3 elements, it will produce 2 and 1 element(s) in lists.

The following pairing function also pullS the last straggler from the list.

```
 pairs = takeWhile (not.null) . map (take 2) . iterate (drop 2)
```

I think the following is better. It is set up for pairs but can be parameterized to do any size chunk. It will take any list and include single elements.

```
np ls = [take 2 (drop a ls)|a<-[0,2..(length ls)-1]]
```