# Converting from one representation of a "Shape" to another

Tags: haskell

The following definitions represent a shape composed of coloured squares at specific coordinates on a grid:

```
type AltShape = [Point]
data Point = P Colour (Int,Int)  deriving Eq
data Colour = Black | Red | Green | Blue  deriving Eq
```

I should asume that coordinates always are positive and the coordinate (0,0) refers to the top left square of the picture, and the y-coordinates grow downwards

A Red L-shape could be represented by

```
lShape = [P Red (0,0), P Red (0,1), P Red (0,2), P Red (1,2)]
```

A different way to represent such shapes is as a list-of-lists, one list for each row:

```
type Shape = [Row] 
type Row   = [Square]
type Square = Maybe Colour
```

For example, the red L-shape above would be represented by the following value of type Shape:

```
lShape2 = [[x,o]
          ,[x,o]
          ,[x,x]] where x = Just Red
                        o = Nothing
```

My task is to define a function `toShape :: AltShape -> Shape` that converts from a AltShape to an Shape. I had another task to define a function `fromShape :: Shape -> AltShape` but where `data Shape = S [Row]`. I found that rather simple and wrote it like this:

```
    fromShape :: Shape -> AltShape
    fromShape (S rows) = [ P c (x,y) | (y,row) <- index rows, (x,Just c) <- index row]
     where index = zip [0..]
```

However, I am having more trouble with this one. I started by creating the function

```
colourAndCoords :: Point -> (Colour,(Int,Int))
colourAndCoords ( P c (x,y) ) = (c,(x,y))
```

I then created a function

```
coords :: [Point] -> [(Int,Int)]
coords ps = map snd (map colourAndCoords ps)
```

My thought was to compare this list to another list of all possible coordinations and where there was a match add the right colour, and where there wasn't I would add Nothing. However, my teacher said I was making it too complicated and that I should think of another solution. But I am having a hard time thinking of one. So I guess my question is what is the easier way? I am not asking for a solution, just a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks a ton for anyone taking the time to read this and respond!!

If I come up with a solution I will come back and update this thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an efficient solution, the [`accumArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.3.0/docs/Data-Array.html#v:accumArray) function does almost exactly what you need (after computing the appropriate bounds).

```
λ> arr = accumArray (const Just) Nothing ((0, 0), (2, 1)) [((y, x), c) | P c (x, y) <- lShape]
λ> arr
array ((0,0),(2,1)) [((0,0),Just Red),((0,1),Nothing),((1,0),Just Red),((1,1),Nothing),((2,0),Just Red),((2,1),Just Red)]
λ> elems arr
[Just Red,Nothing,Just Red,Nothing,Just Red,Just Red]
```

Now the problem is reduced to [split elements into groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25617970/115030).

```
λ> chunksOf 2 (elems arr)
[[Just Red,Nothing],[Just Red,Nothing],[Just Red,Just Red]]
```

For a real application you’d probably want to leave it as an array, since array indexing is fast (*O*(1)) and list indexing is slow (*O*(*n*)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I don't think I am supposed to use any libraries except the basic one (Data.List, Char etc...). Looks good tho :)

Comment: It’s up to you which libraries to use, but for the record, `Data.Array` is [part of the language spec](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch14.html#x22-20100014) and [included in GHC](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/8.6.2-notes.html#included-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is no concern, you could consider this approach:

1. Figure out the largest x coordinate (call it w), and the largest y coordinate (call it h).
2. Create a rectangular list of lists, length w by h, with a list comprehension or similar. At each position, look through the entire list of points for one with a matching position, and use its color if you find one (`Nothing` otherwise).

If efficiency is a concern, you could consider a more complicated approach:

1. Turn your `[AltShape]` into an `IntMap (IntMap Colour)`, e.g. using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12398458/791604), which maps y and x to colour.
2. Iterate over occupied rows with `toAscList`; within each, iterate over occupied columns with `toAscList`. You will need to manually pad unoccupied rows with `[]` and unoccupied columns with `Nothing`.

An advantage (or possibly disadvantage, depending on your goals!) of the second approach is that it will naturally produce "ragged" `Shape`s which omit trailing `Nothing`s.